# CONNECT BY PRIOR and concatenation of parent - child hierarchy

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**I have this table:**

[img](https://i.ibb.co/6mHspXs/imagem.png)

**Desired result:**

[img](https://i.ibb.co/cx5PVJq/imagem.png)

**What i'm trying:**

`select SEG from my_table CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_SEG_ID = SEG_ID;`

So, in the column LEVEL_LOCATOR we can see f.e. that the LEVEL 5.9 has 6 childs, and 5.9.4 has 2 childs. 
And, f.e., the parent of the child 5.9.1 is Postpaid that has the SEG_ID = 361978 and it's in the row of this child as PARENT_SEG_ID. So **parent and child connect with SEG_ID and PARENT_SEG_ID.**

I'm trying to do this but so far i can't have the result i want.

**Note:** The col_a is the concatenation SEG column in the following format: `parent - child - child` (if it has childs)

Comment: Please edit your question to have the table and results as formatted text, not images. Not everyone can see them, and it makes it much harder to recreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to walk the tree the other way around, and can then use [`sys_connect_by_path()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.html) to concatenate the segment names, and [`connect_by_isleaf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html) to only show the leaf nodes:

```
select col_a, col_b
from (
  select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(seg, ' - '), ' - ') as col_a,
    seg_id as col_b,
    connect_by_isleaf as isleaf
  from my_table
  start with seg = 'Prepaid'
  connect by parent_seg_id = prior seg_id
)
where isleaf = 1;

COL_A                                                   COL_B
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Prepaid                                                361977
Prepaid - Voice Mobile                             2687522995
Prepaid - Internet Mobile                          2687525564
Prepaid - Data Mobile                              2687527808
Prepaid - Voice Fixa - Default                     2687531979
Prepaid - Voice Fixa - Internal PABX               2687534794
```

The `ltrim()` is there to remove an extra `-` that the path includes at the start.

But you need a starting condition; I've gone with 'Prepaid', which includes an extra row in the output, but you could `start with seg_id = 361978` instead, or some other condition depending on what data you actually want to see.

You could also using consider recursive subquery factoring.